# How to place horizontal scrollbar at top of ResourceTimeline in fullcalendar angular12

Tags: javascript, css, angular, fullcalendar

When there is plenty of resources in resourceTimeline i have to scroll to bottom for horizontal scroll bar and it is time consuming.

I have tried css , but it is not working on fullcalender , all the view is set to opposite side.

Comment: It's better you share what you've tried so far, and the relevant part of the code. Currently, it's impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: This isn't currently a feature, you'll need a [request it](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) from the project maintainers, I would expect.